# IOS 13: CoreLocation: CLVisit stop calling delegate after a while

Tags: core-location, ios13

after upgrading my iPhone to IOS 13.* the *DidVisit* callback of the *CoreLocation delegate* is not fired reliable anymore.

I didn't change any code in this area. All works well since IOS 9 (start of the development of the app).

It's starts as usual, but after a while it stops calling the callback "didVisit" and than nothing brings it back to life (sometimes reboots are healing, sometimes new app version), but I do not see any pattern...

Does anybody see the same problem?

***EDIT:***

As Nevan King told me it should work even with IOS 13, I will now provide the related code blocks and the log of a run this morning. Maybe someone can tell me what is wrong with the code...

The location manager is working and the delegate callbacks (didUpdateLocations, didEnterRegion etc. etc.) are all called, except the callback "didVisit".

It's really strange!

First: this is the methode to set the location manager

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// startRunLoop()
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
func startRunLoop(preferMain: Bool) {

    // before we start the location manager we wait for the user accepted the privacy explanation
    checkAndWaitForStartViewController(from: "WTSRunLoop startRunLoop(preferMain: \(preferMain)")

    // explicit call on main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

        #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
        NSLog("WTSRunLoop: set WTS_LocationManager, his delegate, WTS_MotionActivityManager and WTS_MotionActivityQueue")
        #endif

        // ---------------------------------------
        // first step, just cean up left overs, just to be on the save side
        if self.WTS_LocationManager != nil {
            if self.WTS_LocationManager!.delegate != nil {
                self.WTS_LocationManager!.delegate = nil
                #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
                NSLog("WTSRunLoop: just set WTS_LocationManager!.delegate = nil, as it was not nil")
                #endif
            }
            self.WTS_LocationManager = nil
            #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
            NSLog("WTSRunLoop: just set WTS_LocationManager = nil, as it was not nil")
            #endif
        }

        // get the location manager and set the delegate
        self.WTS_LocationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.WTS_LocationManager!.delegate = self


        // set the semaphore, that we did create the location manager
        #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
        NSLog("WTSRunLoop: call WTS_LocationManagerDispatchGroup.leave()")
        #endif
        WTS_LocationManagerDispatchGroup.leave()

        ...

     })
}
```

Second: the methode to start the visit monitoring

```
/**
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 WTS_StartVisitMonitoring()

 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
var WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone : Bool = false
func WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(checkRegion: Bool) {

    #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
    NSLog("WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): just started")
    #endif

    // just a test if we still run on the same locationManager
    if self.WTS_LocationManager != nil {

        if self.WTS_OldLocationManager != self.WTS_LocationManager {

            #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
            NSLog("WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): WTS_OldLocationManager (\(self.WTS_OldLocationManager.debugDescription)) != WTS_LocationManager (\(self.WTS_LocationManager.debugDescription)), set WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone = false")
            #endif
            WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone = false
            self.WTS_OldLocationManager = self.WTS_LocationManager
        }
    }

    // make sure we do this only once
    if self.WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone == false {

        // set the flag
        self.WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone = true

        // if we didn't have a valif location manager so far, wait for it
        if self.WTS_LocationManager == nil {

            #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
            NSLog("WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): WTS_LocationManager == nil, call WTS_LocationManagerDispatchGroup.wait()")
            #endif

            WTS_LocationManagerDispatchGroup.wait()
        }

        #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
        NSLog("WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): will try to call WTS_LocationManager!.startMonitoringVisits() on main thread")
        #endif

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
            NSLog("WTS_StartVisitMonitoring().main: call WTS_LocationManager!.startMonitoringVisits() on main thread")
            #endif

            self.WTS_LocationManager!.startMonitoringVisits()
        })

        // check if we should do a check to adjust the visits Region
        if checkRegion == true {

            #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
            NSLog("WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): checkRegion == true, will call WTS_CheckForVisitRegion()")
            #endif
            self.WTS_CheckForVisitRegion()
        }

    } else {

        #if DEBUG_NSLOG_CUR
        NSLog("WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone == \(self.WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone), do nothing")
        #endif
    }
}
```

Third: the relevant parts of the log of a run this morning.

```
2019-11-08 06:10:13.647 App[2156:734589] WTSRunLoop init(), <<< IOS 13 >>> now call startRunLoop(true)
2019-11-08 06:10:13.647 App[2156:734589] checkAndWaitForStartViewController(from: WTSRunLoop startRunLoop(preferMain: true): just started, will call now myStartupDispatchGroup.wait()

...

2019-11-08 06:10:13.726 App[2156:734589] checkAndWaitForStartViewController(from: WTSRunLoop startRunLoop(preferMain: true): after myStartupDispatchGroup.wait(), return
2019-11-08 06:10:13.727 App[2156:734584] WTSRunLoop: set WTS_LocationManager, his delegate, WTS_MotionActivityManager and WTS_MotionActivityQueue
2019-11-08 06:10:13.728 App[2156:734589] WTS_StartTrackSystem(): just started, wait for StartViewController
2019-11-08 06:10:13.728 App[2156:734584] WTSRunLoop: call WTS_LocationManagerDispatchGroup.leave()
2019-11-08 06:10:13.728 App[2156:734584] WTSRunLoop: WTS_MotionActivityManager != nil, all OK
2019-11-08 06:10:13.728 App[2156:734584] WTSRunLoop: WTS_MotionActivityQueue != nil, all OK

...

2019-11-08 06:10:14.435 App[2156:734584] locationManager(didChangeAuthorization:): just started, call checkAndHandleAuthorizationStatus()
2019-11-08 06:10:14.436 App[2156:734584] checkAndHandleAuthorisationStatus(): User gave permission to use Localisation also when not in use, now we can work
2019-11-08 06:10:14.436 App[2156:734584] checkAndHandleAuthorisationStatus(): user decided about authorization, call myAuthorizationDispatchGroup.leave()
2019-11-08 06:10:14.436 App[2156:734584] locationManager(didChangeAuthorization:): new authorizationStatus = .authorizedAlways

....

2019-11-08 06:10:14.438 App[2156:734589] WTS_SetYellowRed(): will call WTS_StartVisitMonitoring()
2019-11-08 06:10:14.438 App[2156:734589] WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): just started
2019-11-08 06:10:14.439 App[2156:734589] WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): WTS_OldLocationManager (nil) != WTS_LocationManager (Optional(<CLLocationManager: 0x2816b5120>)), set WTS_StartVisitMonitoringDone = false
2019-11-08 06:10:14.439 App[2156:734589] WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): will try to call WTS_LocationManager!.startMonitoringVisits() on myRunLoop
2019-11-08 06:10:14.439 App[2156:734589] WTS_StartVisitMonitoring(): checkRegion == true, will call WTS_CheckForVisitRegion()
...

2019-11-08 06:10:14.497 App[2156:734584] WTS_StartVisitMonitoring().main: call WTS_LocationManager!.startMonitoringVisits() on main thread

...
```

***EDIT 2:***

Believe it or not, after I rebooted my iPhone, the app recieved several didVisit events (see below)...

BUT this are all events from yesterday morning and before. Nothing from yesterday during day and night...

Has anyone an explanation for that behavior ?

```
2019-11-08 08:16:55.700 App[283:5235] didVisit: New VisitEvent: <Lat, Lon>, Arrival: 06.11.2019, 20:21:41, Depart: 01.01.4001, 01:00:00), accuracy: 40.45339263770871
2019-11-08 08:17:00.568 App[283:5235] didVisit: New VisitEvent: <Lat, Lon>, Arrival: 06.11.2019, 20:21:41, Depart: 07.11.2019, 00:47:57), accuracy: 24.207239944549148
2019-11-08 08:17:00.663 App[283:5235] didVisit: New VisitEvent: <Lat, Lon>, Arrival: 07.11.2019, 00:54:20, Depart: 01.01.4001, 01:00:00), accuracy: 85.76831155108509
2019-11-08 08:17:03.698 App[283:5235] didVisit: New VisitEvent: <Lat, Lon>, Arrival: 07.11.2019, 00:54:20, Depart: 07.11.2019, 07:08:39), accuracy: 64.95511399529799
2019-11-08 08:17:03.778 App[283:5235] didVisit: New VisitEvent: <Lat, Lon>, Arrival: 07.11.2019, 07:16:14, Depart: 01.01.4001, 01:00:00), accuracy: 46.553598849932335
2019-11-08 08:17:12.808 App[283:5235] didVisit: New VisitEvent: <Lat, Lon>, Arrival: 07.11.2019, 07:16:14, Depart: 07.11.2019, 07:42:07), accuracy: 105.4615461367936
2019-11-08 08:17:12.909 App[283:5235] didVisit: New VisitEvent: <Lat, Lon>, Arrival: 07.11.2019, 07:50:36, Depart: 01.01.4001, 01:00:00), accuracy: 58.591188713846954
```

.

EDIT 3:

It happened again ... out of the blue, the "didVisit" callback is not called anymore...

I started the app and monitored the device log. I found this in the log, for me it looks good, or do I miss something?

The location deamon confirms the start of visit recording

```
com.apple.locationd.Core    {"msg":"CLLocationManager", "event":"activity", "_cmd":"startMonitoringVisits", "self":"0x282655120"}
```

and later on in a status message I found:

```
locationd   com.apple.locationd.Core    {"msg":"Incoming message", "event":"activity", "name":"kCLConnectionMessageSignificantLocationVisit", "this":"0x10a0476d0", "registrationReceived":1}
locationd   com.apple.locationd.Core    {"msg":"#slv Client subscribe", "client":"myApp", "subscribe":1}
```

and later on I found this (looks as the visit recording started "VisitTimeStarted = ...")

```
locationd   com.apple.locationd.Core    {"msg":"#usesync Enqueued usage update message", "client":"myApp", "usage":"{\n    BackgroundLocationTimeStarted = \"595586042.0572129\";\n    FenceTimeStarted = \"595458288.958685\";\n    LocationTimeStarted = \"595586039.822194\";\n    NonPersistentSignificantTimeStopped = \"586698620.031068\";\n    ReceivingLocationInformationTimeStarted = \"595586039.836334\";\n    SignificantTimeStopped = \"594494158.865963\";\n    VisitTimeStarted = \"595458288.95714\";\n}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLVisit` is still working and the delegate methods are still being called in iOS 13. The permissions system for background location changed in iOS 13 so that background location APIs will only start working after a few days and only if the user grants background permission.

If you want to make visits work immediately, try going to your app settings to toggle the location permission to "Always". It's probably at "When In Use". For more information watch WWDC 2019 [What's New in Core Location](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/)

Comment: Hello Nevan, thank you for your reply, but unfortunately I think that is not the root case. I'm aware of the authorization changes in IOS 13 and addressed it in my code. I have two test devices (iPad and iPhone). Both are on "Always" and on both devices IOS asked already for the re-confirmation. AND The app is using CLRegion for geo fencing and is restarting the app in background. All this works like a charm. So I do not think it's a authorization issue. It is just the CLVisit missing. Apple did once a "silent depreciation" with deferred location updates. So maybe it's the same here?

Comment: Do you ASUME it should work or do you actually see it working under IOS 13?

Comment: I have several test apps where visits are working on iOS 13.

Comment: You probably know these, but some tips from my own debugging of visits: Use local notifications to make sure your methods are being triggered and objects are being created, as well as for any errors that might happen. Make double sure that your location manager is actually created early enough to get the visit.

Comment: Hi Nevan, I checked everything, but I'm lost with this. So I changed my question and provide now the relevant code blocks and the logs ... would you be so kind and take a look? I'm raelly frustrated!

Comment: @Hardy_Germany I had a look at your code but I'm afraid I couldn't understand it. I'd suggest you create a separate, simple test app that just checks to see that visits are working on your device and, if they're working, separate your visits code out into it's own class with its own location manager to simplify things.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. I think we stop here. The issue has gone  - without any code change - after rebooting the test devices and rebuild with Xcode 11.2.1. I'm still confused about the whole thing, but it is not repeatable anymore... so there is no way to dig deeper here. Many, Many Thanks for your help...

Comment: BTW: it happened again! Without any change, the app was running for several mdays, waked up by region border crossings ... and suddenly stoped to send visit events ... this was 2 days ago, after this tried to restart app, rebooted device, reinstalled app, nothing works.